# How to compile with a custom module

Tags: module, makefile, ocaml, ml

I'm trying to compile a project with 2 .ml and one of them is a module follwing this format

```
module Mymodule =  
  struct  
  ...  
  end;;
```

I also created a .mli for myModule

```
module Mymodule =  
  sig  
  ...  
  end
```

But now when I call Mymodule.myfunction in main.ml, I get `"Unbound value Mymodule.myfunction"`.

Here is my makefile (I also have the standard OcamlMakeFile) :

```
RESULT= result  
SOURCES= Mymodule.ml main.ml  
LIBS= bigarray sdl sdlloader sdlttf sdlmixer

INCDIRS= +sdl

include OCamlMakefile
```

I searched and tried some things but nothing is working :(

---

Thanks for your answer, I followed the tutorial you linked but now I've a problem with SDL linking:

```
File "testsdl_2.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Sdl referenced from testsdl_2.cmx
         Sdlloader referenced from testsdl_2.cmx
         Sdlvideo referenced from testsdl_2.cmx
```

and I'm using this line to compile:

```
ocamlopt -I +sdl -o testsdl mymodule.cmx main.ml
```

Answer (score 1):

Each ml source file already represents a module (with the name equal to the name of the file).
Read [ocaml tutorial on modules](http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/ocaml-tutorial.org/modules.html) carefully.

Answer (score 1):

To enlarge a little on ygrek's answer, by declaring a module named Mymodule inside a file named Mymodule.ml, you are creating a module named Mymodule.Mymodule.  Most likely you just want to remove the `module Mymodule` wrappers in the .ml and .mli files and then things will work as you expect.  In essence, OCaml gives you one layer of module wrapping for free with each source file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :)

You have to change the right files "META" in the used libraries. In my case, the META file in the library `odepack` have to be changed by adding the following line

```
requires = "bigarray"
```

After that, a minor modification in the Makefile have to be done. The line

```
LIBS = unix str bigarray
```

is modified to

```
LIBS = str
```

This modification avoids the error

```
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Files /usr/lib/ocaml/unix.cmxa and /usr/lib/ocaml/unix.cmxa
   both define a module named Unix
```

that occurs when we define the same library twice or more. The library `Bigarray` in my case is sufficient to include the `Unix` library.